# How to change string prefix part in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a `String` in Java with the following path: `E:\HTML\project\img\image.jpg`.

I want to change it to `\img\image.jpg`

How can I do this?

Comment: use substring function   substring(15,29); it will give \img\image.jpg

Comment: Take `\img` as constant string And get the image name by using `s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("\\"), s.length())` This will work for dynamic paths also

Comment: Hi, do you try to change path only for this specific path or for a generic pattern (and you just gave an example of such pattern). You should elaborate in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("E:\\HTML\\project\\img\\image.jpg");
int first = str.lastIndexOf("\\");
int second = str.lastIndexOf("\\", first-1);
System.out.println(str.substring(second));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're asking this but if you simply want to change a string variable into something else it's quite simple:

```
String path = "E:\HTML\project\img\image.jpg";

path = "\img\image.jpg";
```

Except there's one thing you need to change here, either you need to use an escape character like this:

```
path = "\\img\\image.jpg";
```

or simply use the other symbol to declare paths  / .

So if I was you I'd change it into this :

```
String path = "E:/HTML/project/img/image.jpg";

path = "/img/image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "E:\\HTML\\project\\img\\image.jpg";
// find the last backslash
int i1 = path.lastIndexOf("\\");
// find the 2nd last backslash (the one you're after)
int i2 = path.lastIndexOf("\\",i1-1);
// now get the last part of the string
String what_you_want = path.substring(i2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also.

```
String string = "E:/HTML/project/img/image.jpg.";
path = "/img/image.jpg";

String subString = string.substring(path.length()+1, string.length()-1);
System.out.println(subString);
```

or

```
String path = "E:\\HTML\\project\\img\\image.jpg";


System.out.println(path.replace("E:\\HTML\\project", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit complex solution, but works well. I make use of [StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) from Apache Commons.

```
String path = "E:/HTML/project/img/image.jpg";
path = path.substring(StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(path,'/',3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "E:\\HTML\\project\\img\\image.jpg";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"\\");

        System.out.println("---- Split by \\ ------");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String s =st.nextElement().toString();
               if(s.equals("img"))
                   str = s;
               if(s.equals("image.jpg"))
                   str += "\\"+s; 
        }
        System.out.println(str);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "E:\\HTML\\project\\img\\image.jpg";
String newString = s.replaceAll("(.*?)(\\\\img.*)", "$2");
System.out.println(newString);
```